# Angular2 Async issue with child components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component which is loading data from a database. This data comes from my service which returns a promise.

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._massEmpService.fetchFilterFields()
        .then(results => {
            this.fields = {
                areas: results['areas']['options'],
                silos: results['silos']['options'],
                departments: results['departments']['options'],
                locations: results['locations']['options'],
                segments: results['segments']['options'],
                roles: results['roles']['options']
            };
        });
}
```

**Service:**

```
fetchFilterFields() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/fetchImportFields', { "headers": this.headers })
            .map((result: Response) => result.json())
            .subscribe((results) => resolve(results.data));
    });
};
```

I am trying to pass my `this.fields` data to a child component but when I try and use the data in the child component, it doesn't appear to have access to it.

**Child Component:**

```
@Input() fields: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.fields); // No data
}
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<app-import [fields]="fields"></app-import>
```

I believe this is an async issue but I thought using the `afterViewInit` may have solved it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use shared service with `Subject` and `Observable` so that the child component variable can `subscribe` to the data stream.

With the data binding way, child component is loaded with parent, so when `Promise` returns data, child component is not aware of it, hence it needs to be reinitialized to get the data. `Observable` and `subscription` erases that problem.

I have created this [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/vocFx7eoxtE10AvgiwLG?p=preview) that returns promise data to a child component( with added extra 2000ms of delay). If it works for you, you can easily implement it in you code :)

parent.component.ts:

```
constructor(private appState: AppState){ }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.appState
        .fetchFilterFields()
        .then(data => {
          // console.log(data)
          this.appState.setData(data);
        });
}
```

service.ts:

```
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private apiUrl = 'api/data';

  // Observable string source
  private dataStringSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string stream
  dataString$ = this.dataStringSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public setData(value) {
    this.dataStringSource.next(value);
  }

  fetchFilterFields() {
    console.log(this.apiUrl);
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
               .delay(2000)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

child.component.ts:

```
fields: any;

constructor(private appState: AppState){
    // this.mylist = this.appState.get('mylist');

    this.appState.dataString$.subscribe(
      data => {
        // console.log("Subs to child" + data);
        this.fields = data; 
      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngOnChanges()`, which is called every time the value of an input property changes.